# Match words which have given regex around

Tags: regex, scala

I need to get all the text that have two or more spaces "\s{2,}" around them.

Given the following text:

```
IP Address  Name           Location          Type
10.1.10.5   USLAXBOWC01RB  Santa Monica, CA  local
```

I need to extract:

*Line1:* `"IP Address", "Name", "Location", "Type"`
*Line2:* `"10.1.10.5", "USLAXBOWC01RB", "Santa Monica, CA", "local"`

**EDIT:**

Text eligible for extraction:

"`IP Address`" & "`Name`" are two or more spaces apart so they are eligible to be extracted. Similarly, "`Santa Monica, CA`" & "`local`".

Comment: What is the problem? How are you doing this exactly?

Comment: What regex flavour? What's a word to you? Why is a space missing from the first line's "IP Address" ? Is "Santa Monica, CA" from the 3rd line a single match containing a comma, or two separate matches? Why not use a fixed-width text parser?

Comment: Just split on 2 or more spaces.

Comment: @Aaron edited.. let me know if that explains!

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to split your text according the pattern "`\s{2,}`".

Thus, in Python, the regex lib `re` give you all the needed tools:

```
import re
line   = "IP Address  Name           Location          Type"

result = re.split('\s{2,}',line)
```

Which gives:

```
['IP Address', 'Name', 'Location', 'Type']
```

**EDIT**

I guess i understood a little more your question : you more care about isolating a sequence between `\s{2,}`, than splitting it. In your example, however, the solution above seems to be the most suitable.

You asked for a regex, here it is :

```
reg1 = "[^\s](?!\s{2,})(?:.(?!\s{2,}))*[^\s]"
```

1. It first selects a character which is not a space with `[^\s](?!\s{2,})` not followed by two spaces or more. To do so, I used the negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)` ;
2. Then, it isolates a group `(?:...)` composed in this way : any character `.` which is not followed by `\s{2,}` ;
3. Repeat with `*` ;
4. It happens that the final character is not selected if we stop now. So we should add one more `[^\s]`.

A `re.findall(reg1,line)`, and you should be done. One drawback maybe : *it detects sequences which are at least two characters long*.

In that case, an other and simpler regex could eventually complete the job : `reg2 = "\s{2,}([^\s])\s{2,}"`. It selects single non-space characters surrounded by two spaces or more. The use of the bracket `(...)`, forces to return only the character.

By the way, I strongly advise a look on the documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Hope you found what you are looking for :-)

Comment: So isn't there they way we can write a regex for this?

Comment: @codingkapoor `\s{2,}` is a regular expression. Do you mean you would rather use a regex to `match` than to `split`?

Comment: @Aaron Scala has an API that can give me a list of all matches. So I thought of composing a regex as explained above! It would fit with an existing logic. Also, I would learn something new! :)

Comment: @codingkapoor but it also has an API to split strings over a regex pattern, good'ol `String.spilt(String pattern)`, which will be the most efficient way to solve your problem with a regex (note that abstaining from using a regex would likely be even more efficient). The important part regex can play here is describing a sequence of two or more spaces ; you can use this definition as a delimiter while splitting, or you can bother describing more than these and match/find, but that wouldn't be a great use of regex (that can still be a great use of your time depending on existing code)

Comment: Didn't see Scala has been added afterward ; the translation from Python to Scala might not be a problem however

Comment: @AchilleSalaün Could you please explain how to use reg2 along with reg1? Please.

Comment: @codingkapoor `reg1` gives you all the "at least two characters" long  sequences with two spaces or more around, `reg2` gives you single characters surrrounded by two spaces or more. It's the partition of what you want: just concatenate the two results. In other words: `re.findall(reg1,text)` gives you one list `L1`, `re.findall(reg2,text)` gives you a second list `L2`, what you need to do is `L=L1+L2`.

Something like `reg1|reg2` should work, but I've not been succesful however there: the management of groups by `re` shown to me some resistances. The best solution i got:  `reg2|(reg1)`.